# NodeJS+mongo: How many connections in a pool are actually being used?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get a sense if my connection pool sizes are big enough. I can't seem to find any hints on seeing how many connections within the pool are available or in use.  I would love to just graph this over time.  Alternatively, is there a way to see the high water mark for the maximum number of concurrent connections in use within the pool?

MongoDB 4.2
mongodb nodejs 3.5.8
Mongoose 5.9.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [CMAP event subscriber](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/reference/management/cmap-monitoring/) to receive notifications when connections are created and closed.

I am unaware of standardized driver functionality to obtain the current pool size, but you can figure it out by tracking connection creation.